# Publishing Photo to Glass Timeline using GDK and NOT Mirror

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk, google-mirror-api

I am working on a Google Glass application that will apply a filter and then take pictures. We used to use Card and TimelineManager to do this, but both were discontinued.

I'm currently using CardBuilder in replacement of Card, and I am able to take the photo and save it in Glass memory, but I would also like the photos to show up with the rest of the pictures taken outside my application (directly from Glass).

Most suggestions I found to publishing to Timeline require using Mirror. However, I don't want my application to require Internet access. Is there a way to publish to the Timeline without using Mirror?

I'm new to Glass and Android coding so any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried TimelineManager before but I think [Live cards](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/live-cards) is what you're looking for. It's used for publishing information to the timeline. No access to the internet required.

The [doc](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/live-cards) has the sample code and some [sample apps](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-stopwatch-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/glass/sample/stopwatch/StopwatchService.java) also use it.

Note: [Static card is not supported by GDK as of now](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=320).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like the picture to stay in the Timeline forever. I think Live Cards are supposed to be destroyed once the user is done with them, but I don't want the pictures to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two things. If you want the picture to appear to the left of the time (which would mean foreverish) then you want to use Live Card as suggested above. However, if you want to add it to the timeline (which is to the right of the time) then you can't add that via the GDK anymore.

Google felt that the Mirror API was built specifically for this and the Timeline Manager defeated the purpose of it so it was removed.